# JS - Как сравнить два массива и получить массив с отличающимися элементами?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть два массива с объектами. Объекты с одинаковыми именами свойств.

```
arr1 = [{name:'vasya', t:'1'},{name:'petya', t:'1'},{name:'senya', t:'1'},{name:'zaza', t:'1'},{name:'dada', t:'1'}  и т.д.];
arr2 = [{name:'pasha', t:'1'},{name:'senya', t:'1'},{name:'petya', t:'1'},{name:'misha', t:'1'},{name:'vasya', t:'1'}];
```

Как из `arr2` исключить элементы (по свойству `name`), которые уже имеются в `arr1` и получить массив с различиями `arr3`?

```
arr3 = [{name:'pasha', t:'1'},{name:'misha', t:'1'}]
```

Comment: где-то я уже видел этот вопрос два раза

Answer (score 1):

Используя стандартные функции javascript, можно отфильтровать второй массив, используя метод [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), оставив в нем только те элементы, индексы которых не найдены в первом массиве при помощи метода [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
const arr1 = [
  {name:'vasya', t:'1'},
  {name:'petya', t:'1'},
  {name:'senya', t:'1'},
  {name:'zaza', t:'1'},
  {name:'dada', t:'1'}
];

const arr2 = [
  {name:'pasha', t:'1'},
  {name:'senya', t:'1'},
  {name:'petya', t:'1'},
  {name:'misha', t:'1'},
  {name:'vasya', t:'1'}
];

const arr3 = arr2.filter(e=>arr1.findIndex(i=>i.name == e.name) === -1);

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что перебором можно решить эту задачу

```
arr1 = [{name:'vasya', t:'1'},{name:'petya', t:'1'},{name:'senya', t:'1'},{name:'zaza', t:'1'},{name:'dada', t:'1'}];
arr2 = [{name:'pasha', t:'1'},{name:'senya', t:'1'},{name:'petya', t:'1'},{name:'misha', t:'1'},{name:'vasya', t:'1'}];
k=0;
arr3 = [{name: '', t:''}]
for(i=0;i<arr2.length;i++){
  b=1;
  for(j=0;j<arr1.length;j++){
    if(arr2[i].name==arr1[j].name){
      b=0;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(b==1){
    arr3[k++]=arr2[i];
  }
}
```